# Acquiring the city location of where my device is at

Tags: c++, qt, geolocation, qt6

Now I am using Qt, and using the following libraries:

```
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QGeoLocation>
```

The farthest I've got was acquiring the longitude and latitude of my device. The device(s) in question all use Windows 11, tablets all of them. So obviously the goal here is pin pointing where they are.

In my app as soon as the user signs In I'm supposed to get the location. How do I go on about that now that I have the longitude and latitude, to find the city the device is in that is?

These are some parts of my code:

```
LoginWindow::LoginWindow(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::LoginWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    GeoSource = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
    qDebug()<<GeoSource;
    delay(2000);
    qDebug()<<GeoSource;
    requestGPSlocation();

    if (GeoSource)
    {
        qDebug() << "GPS :: GeoSource is valid";
        qDebug()<<"check 1";
        connect(GeoSource, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo))            , this , SLOT(GPS_positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
        qDebug()<<"check 2";
        connect(GeoSource, SIGNAL(errorOccurred(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error)) , this , SLOT(GPS_errorOccurred(QGeoPositionInfoSource::Error)));
        qDebug()<<"check 3";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "GPS :: GeoSource isn't valid \n" << GeoSource->availableSources();
    }


}
    
    

This is the function that gets called to acquire the geo-location:



    void LoginWindow::GPS_positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
{
    qDebug()<<"Entered Function: :::: :";
    //=========================================================
    qDebug() << "GPS_positionUpdated ::: latitude = "
             << info.coordinate().latitude()
             << " , longitude = " << info.coordinate().longitude();

    //=========================================================
    QGeoCoordinate coordinate = info.coordinate();
        double latitude = coordinate.latitude();
        double longitude = coordinate.longitude();


        qDebug() << "Latitude:" << latitude;
        qDebug() << "Longitude:" << longitude;
        longAndLat << QString::number(longitude) << QString::number(latitude);
        qDebug()<<"coordinates: "<<longAndLat;
        qDebug()<<"Size: "<<longAndLat.size();

    //=========================================================
        qDebug()<<"AVAILABLE SERVICE PROVIDERS: "<<QGeoServiceProvider::availableServiceProviders();

        // create a parameter map
        QMap<QString, QVariant> parameters;

        parameters["osm.useragent"] = "MiLink";
        parameters["osm.mapping.copyright"] = "2ana";
        parameters["osm.geocoding.host"] = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/";

        // create a feature list
//        QGeoServiceProvider::RoutingFeatures features;
//        features |= QGeoServiceProvider::OnlineRoutingFeature;
//        features |= QGeoServiceProvider::RouteUpdatesFeature;

        // Reverse geocode the coordinates to obtain the address information
        QGeoServiceProvider serviceProvider("osm", parameters); // Choose the desired provider
        QGeoCodingManager *geoCodingManager = serviceProvider.geocodingManager();
        QGeoCodeReply *reply = geoCodingManager->reverseGeocode(coordinate);

        qDebug() << "Reply object:" << reply
        << ",Error:" << reply->error()
        << ",Error String:" << reply->errorString()
        << ",Locations:" << reply->locations().isEmpty();
        qDebug()<<"Reverse Coding Result CALLED (BEFORE)";

        connect(reply, &QGeoCodeReply::finished, this, [this,reply] (){

        // call your handleReverseGeocodingResult function
        handleReverseGeocodingResult(reply);

        });
//        connect(reply, &QGeoCodeReply::finished, this, &LoginWindow::handleReverseGeocodingResult);
//         if (!result) {
//             qDebug() << "Connection failed";
//         }else{
//             qDebug() << "Connection succeeded";
//         }
         qDebug() << "Reply object:" << reply
         << ",Error:" << reply->error()
         << ",Error String:" << reply->errorString()
         << ",Locations:" << reply->locations().isEmpty();
         qDebug()<<"Reverse Coding Result CALLED (AFTER)";



        emit locationIsUpdatedSignal();

        GeoSource->stopUpdates();


        QString device_serialNo = getDeviceSerialNumber();
        QString location_coordinates = "("+longAndLat[0] + "," + longAndLat[1]+")";
        sendEmailToAdmin("tablet_model_location" ,device_serialNo, location_coordinates);

}
```

Edit: I made some changes to my code, the issue now is that I am not receiving a response form the service provider and I don't know why

Comment: You have to query a database which city is the nearest to this location, either by using an online service, or by providing your own offline database.

Comment: It is called reverse geocoding

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I'm working on that and will update the code, but then how do I acquire the result?